# Как сделать редирект с домена на другой ip без файла host

Tags: apache, redirect, browsers

Есть хостинг с загруженным на него сайтом. Домен для сайта не куплен. Чтобы перейти на сайт и протестировать, для начала, в файле хост необходимо прописать запись следующего вида:
111.111.111.111 mydomain.ru
Т.е. ip хостера и домен который я придумал и записал у хостера.

Просто, перейдя по ip адресу такого эффекта не получится. Как я понял сервер apache определяет какой домен и в зависимости от этого показывает контент нужного пользователя.

Так вот, суть вопроса. Как мне  перейти на мой сайт, когда я не имею доступа к файлу host. Т.е. обратиться на ip 111.111.111.111 и при это сказать серверу, что обращаюсь с домена mydomain.ru, БЕЗ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЯ ФАЙЛА HOST. Или как добиться редиректа как через файл host без использования файла host.

Comment: Хостер не дает домен третьего уровня для тестирования что ли?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Объяню в двух словах:
Домен преобразовывается в IP адрес сервера, на котором размещен сайт. Для преобразования доменного имени в IP адрес серврера используются запросы к DNS серврерам. На одном сервере может находится множество сайтов, один IP адрес может быть у тысячи доменов. Серврер определяет к какому сайту поступил запрос считывая загаловки и сопоставляя запрос со списком виртуальных хостов.
На своем компьютере в файле host вы прописали IP адрес вашего сайта. Перед DNS запросом браузер проверяет файл host, преобразовует домен в адрес вашего серврера и отправляет запрос. Сервер находит виртуальный хост и обрабатывает ваш запрос.
С другой стороны, ваш хостинг провайдер должен предоставлять технический домен для доступа к сайту.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться с хостером по поводу технического домена. Хотя бы подсказали в каком направлении двигаться.